# Android: 'onNotification' not executing when app is closed and clicked to notification

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

I am using react-native-pushnotification.
here is the module link
https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification
in ios notifications working fine when in background and foreground also, but in android foreground it is working fine, But in background i got the notification, when click on that notification app getting relaunch and not showing any alert in android,

1. In iOS these functionalities are working fine. But in android i am facing this problem

Can any one give me some suggestion that how to resolve it, Any help much appreciated.

Comment: what did you try since then? can you please post the code how you are handling it in iOS? for your information I handle this case using redux.

Answer (score 0):

To show alert in android :
in your android device -> settings -> App Notification -> select your app name and turn on all the show notifications. this will show alert. Hope this works.